# Unable to resolve "firebase" error in React Native project

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I try to use Firebase in a ReactNative project.
I added all the configurations data in a `config.js` file :

`<Project_Name>\src\firebase\config.js`

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  appId: '...',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export { firebase };
```

And here is how I try to use that :

<Project_Name>\src\screens\RegistrationScreen\RegistrationScreen.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';

import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config'
// const firebase = require('../../firebase/config');
// const firebase = require('./src/firebase/config');

export default function RegistrationScreen({navigation}) {
    ...
}
```

But here's the error I get whatever I try :
`Unable to resolve "firebase" from "src\firebase\config.js"`

---

Sorry if the question has already been asked but I don't understand what the problem could be (I swear I checked the similar questions)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a compatibility error between the dependency versions... I took the time to select compatible versions for each of them and the problem was resolved.

So if you encounter the same problem, try checking the versions of your dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible to add more information, which versions of dependencies and to what?